# How to fix tiny title bar icons in certain 3rd party apps on hiDPI devices

Tags: release-freya, macbook, pixel-density

I'm using elementary OS on my Retina MacBook Pro 10,1 again.

Certain 3rd party apps (including Firefox, and also gedit as root) have rather tiny control buttons (close, minimize, maximize) in the title bar. The font size is OK, but the mouse pointer also changes size while hovering over the title bar.

Is there a way to fix this?

[image: rMBP 10,1 eOS Freya Firefox]

Comment: This should reported as a bug. See above for details on how to do that. Thanks!